# cURL get values and pass to next page and get result

Tags: php, post, curl

I have a form. Using cURL I get this response:

```
<form id="Homepage" action="/WebApp/home.htm" method="post">
    <div id="searchElements">
        <input id="imeiNumber" type="hidden" name="imeiNumber" value=""/>
        <input type="hidden" name="tokenEncrypted" id="tokenEncrypted"  value="GQ5SA0FDIHDH6WWNR1TC3UVVUIEBFNMVYDDL7UCX9A"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="tokenTimeStamp" id="tokenTimeStamp" value="1448839083432"/>
</form>
```

Here I need to pass value `imeiNumber` to get my result.

Do I need to temporary save `tokenEncrypted` and `tokenTimeStamp` and pass them together with imeiNumber if using cURL?

Here is my code to get results above:

```
<?php
$cook = "/cookie/gsx.txt";
$site = "www.mywebsite.com";
$data = "imeiNumber=357996051632600";
$curl = curl_init('https://'.$site.'/WebApp/home.htm');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Connection: keep-alive',
    'Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
    'Origin: https://'.$site,
    'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest',
    'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 6_1_4 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Mobile/10B350 Safari/8536.25',
    'Referer: https://'.$site.'/WebApp/resource.htm',
    )   );
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cook);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
echo $der1 = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
?>
```

How can I save this values and pass them in my request?

Comment: I would say the answer is yes

Comment: @RamRaider could you please show a sample of how to do that in your answer?

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `DOMDocument` on the returned html like this.

```
<?php

    libxml_use_internal_errors( true );
    $dom=new DOMDocument;
    $dom->validateOnParse=false;
    $dom->recover=true;
    $dom->loadHTML( $der1 );
    libxml_clear_errors();

    $params=array(
        'imeiNumber'        =>  '357996051632600',
        'tokenEncrypted'    =>  $dom->getElementById('tokenEncrypted')->nodeValue,
        'tokenTimeStamp'    =>  $dom->getElementById('tokenTimeStamp')->nodeValue
    );
    $dom=null;

    /* params for the curl POST request */
    $params=http_build_query( $params );

    /* curl stuff */

?>
```

Comment: So I run cURL 2 times before this DOM and after again.. Do I need to 'curl_close($curl);' before this DOM code? Or only do curl_close($curl); on end?

Comment: yep - you will need to do another curl request ( POST ) using the `$params` as the POST data - what and how you deal with the response from this next curl request is up to you. Close curl at the end should be ok.